# extract disease names from raw data which has no pattern

Tags: python, analytics, bigdata

I want to extract disease words from medical data to make a disease word dictionary (consider the notes written by doctors, test results). I'm using python. I tried the following ways:

1. Used google API to check whether the word is a disease or not depending on the results. It didn't go well because it was extracting medical words too and i even tried modify the search and also i had to buy google CSE which i feel is costly because i have huge data. Its a huge code to include in the post.
2. Used weka to predict the words but the data which i have is normal text data and wont follow any rules and not in ARFF or CSV type.
3. Tried checking NER for extracting disease words. But, all the models which i have seen needed a predefined dictionary to search and perform tf-idf on the input data. I don't have such kind of dictionary.
4. In all the models which i have seen they suggest me to tokenize then POS for the data which I did and couldn't find another way to extract only the disease words.
5. I even tried extracting only the nouns which didn't do well because other medical terms were also considered as nouns.

My data is in the following way and doesn't follow the same way in the whole document:

> After conducting clinical reviews the patient was suffering with
>   diabetes,htn which was revealed when a complete blood picture of the
>   patient's blood was done. He was advised to take PRINIVIL TABS 20 MG
>   (LISINOPRIL) 1.

Believe me, I googled a lot and couldn't come with a perfect solution. Please suggest a way for me to move forward.

The following is one of the approaches I tried which extracted the medical terms too. Sorry, the code looks a bit clumsy and i am positing the main function in it as posting the whole code will be veryy lenghty. Look the search_word variable main logic lies there :

```
def search(self,wordd): #implemented google custom search engine api
  #responseData = 'None'
  global flag
  global page
  search_word="\"is+%s+an+organ?\"" %(wordd)
  search_word=str(search_word)
  if flag == 1:
   search_word="\"%s+is+a+disease\"" %(wordd)
  try: #searching google for the word
   url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyAUGKCa2oHSYeZynSMD6zElBKUrg596G_k&cx=00262342415310682663:xy7prswaherw&num=3&q='+search_word
   print url
   data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
   response_data = json.load(data)
   results=response_data['queries']['request'][0]['totalResults']
   results_count=int(results)
   print "the results is: ",results_count
   if(results_count == 0):
    print "no results found"
    flag = 0
    return 0
   else:
    return 1
  #except IOError:
   #print "network issues!"
  except ValueError:
   print "Problem while decoding JSON data!"
```

Comment: If you didn't find a *perfect* solution, did you find *any* solution? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Looks like you already put a lot of work in. But since it's hard to distinguish between disease names, other nouns and other medical terms, what exactly is the problem with building up a dictionary of all known disease names (e.g. by parsing medical resources) and then checking the text for those? I don't think there's much else you can do if you don't have clear rules on what constitutes for a disease name.

Comment: @DisplayName "Have you tried anything?" <- Have you read anything?

Comment: "Tried anything" = "Show us the code you have tried"

Comment: @timegb Thats what the main problem i have. The disease name in the data wont follow a pattern.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @timegb . Surely scraping a list like [this](http://www.medicinenet.com/diseases_and_conditions/alpha_a.htm) would be easier than the current approach? I'm not clear on what you mean by dictionary though. Are you trying to associate symptoms with diseases or just have a list of unique diseases? If the latter, at least you would have a starting point?

Comment: @roganjosh. No i am not trying to associate symptoms with diseases. I just need a dictionary of unique disease. I could extract disease words along with medical data with the current approach which i came up with

Comment: Ok, so as I understand it, even scraping a web resource like I listed is not sufficient because the final list would have things like "fever" rather than just specific disease names? I doubt there is a "perfect" solution here. My approach would be to scrape as many lists as possible like the one that I provided. Then combine into something like a bag-of-words. Any term from the medical notes that passes your initial test is cross-referenced against your scraped data in the hope you'll filter out more noise.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this link http://www.malacards.org/, MalaCards: The human disease database. 19,915 disease entries, consolidated from 68 sources, which along the lines suggested by  roganjosh in their last comment.